# Display selected button value php

Tags: php, html, post, get

Here is an html form. I want to print the value of button selected.
I have tried some code but it is not working.

**HTML**

```
<form method='post' name="letter" >
<input type='submit' name='A' value='A'/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='B' value='B'/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='G' value='G'/><br/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$selected_val='';
if(isset($_GET['letter'])){
$selected_val = $_GET['letter'];
}
echo $selected_val;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set same name for all the submit button

**HTML**

```
<form method='post' name="letter" >
<input type='submit' name='getValue' value='A'/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='getValue' value='B'/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='getValue' value='G'/><br/>
</form>
```

Get the value with button name

**PHP**

```
<?php
$selected_val='';
if(isset($_POST['getValue'])){
$selected_val = $_POST['getValue'];
}
echo $selected_val;
?>
```